# change environment in evil-tex

Tags: latex, evil, math

I'm discovering evil-tex, it seems great : I already like the possibility to switch from equation* to equation and vice-versa. There is a manipulation I do very often which is to change \begin{equation} into \begin{multiline*} when it is too long.
I didn't find the correct shortcuts. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/iyefrat/evil-tex#environment-keymap), the environment keymap for `multiline*` is `M`.

So for example from inside your `equation` environment in `evil-normal-state`, you can change the `equation` environment to `multiline*` with `cseeM`. From `multiline*` to `equation` would be `cseee`.